# What should I be looking for to alter the data of all values in a column

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to be able to add 15% to all the numbers in every row of a specific column. If someone could point me in the right direction that would be great.

example:

current price is 200
change price to 200*1.15
new price is 230

Answer (score 2):

```
UPDATE [Table] SET [Column] = [Column] * 1.15
```

Comment: That is a lot simpler than I thought it would be, thanks